# How safe is UDP?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I'm considering whether to use TCP or UDP for some really simple communication I'm working on. Here are the basic details:

- All messages fit in a single 1500-byte packet (so ordering is irrelevant)
- The recipient of these messages will be bombarded with packets from a number of different sources. TCP would handle congestion, but would UDP packets arriving at the same port simultaneously from tens or hundreds of sources corrupt each other?
- Missed/corrupted messages are not a big deal. So long as they remain a small minority, and they are correctly identified as invalid, they can just be ignored
- Packets arrive in waves, a few per second for a few seconds and then tens of thousands in a fraction of a second. The network should be able to handle the bandwidth in these spikes

Do you see any problem with using UDP for this, keeping in mind that ordering doesn't matter, lost/corrupted packets can be safely ignored, and these packet spikes will have tens of thousands of packets arriving possibly simultaneously?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it sounds like you need to use UDP. UDP has less overhead (meaning smaller package size) well suited for rapid delivery; Package loss can occur, but it sounds like it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

> All messages fit in a single 1500-byte packet (so ordering is irrelevant)

1500 is the MTU usually used in local networks. It can be lower on the internet and protocols like DNS assume that at least 512 byte will work. But even if the MTU is lower the packet gets only fragmented and reassembled at the end, so no half messages arrive at the application.

> ..  but would UDP packets arriving at the same port simultaneously from tens or hundreds of sources corrupt each other?

They would not corrupt each other. If they arrive too fast and your application is not able to read them in time from the socket buffer so that the socket buffer fills up then the packet will simply be lost.

> Missed/corrupted messages are not a big deal. So long as they remain a small minority, and they are correctly identified as invalid, they can just be ignored

There is an optional checksum for UDP which gets used in most cases. If the checksum does not fit the packet gets discarded, i.e. not delivered to the application. The checksum does account for simple bitflips but will not be able to detect every corruption. But this is the same with all checksums and also with TCP.

> Packets arrive in waves, a few per second for a few seconds and then tens of thousands in a fraction of a second. The network should be able to handle the bandwidth in these spikes

If the bandwidth in the network can deal with it then the network is able to handle it. But the question is if your local machine and especially your application is able to cope with such waves, that is to process packets that fast  that the buffer of the network card and the socket buffer not overflow. You should probably increase the receive buffer size to better deal with such waves.

Answer (score 1):

> All messages fit in a single 1500-byte packet (so ordering is irrelevant)

*Non sequitur.* The generally accepted payload limit for UDP datagrams is 534 bytes, and the fact that all messages fit into one datagram doesn't imply that order is irrelevant, *unless* the order of *messages* is irrelevant, which you haven't stated.

> would UDP packets arriving at the same port simultaneously from tens or hundreds of sources corrupt each other?

No.

> Missed/corrupted messages are not a big deal. So long as they remain a small minority, and they are correctly identified as invalid, they can just be ignored.

If you don't disable UDP checksum checking, they will be dropped, not ignored.

> Packets arrive in waves, a few per second for a few seconds and then tens of thousands in a fraction of a second. The network should be able to handle the bandwidth in these spikes.

It won't. UDP packets can be dropped any time, especially under conditions like these. But as you've already stated that missed messages are not a big deal, it isn't a big deal.

> Do you see any problem with using UDP for this, keeping in mind that ordering doesn't matter, lost/corrupted packets can be safely ignored, and these packet spikes will have tens of thousands of packets arriving possibly simultaneously?

Not under the conditions you have stated, assuming they are correct.

Comment: The order of messages is irrelevant, and any single message fits into a 1500-byte packet. The accepted payload accounts for all the extra headers one can stuff into UDP, almost none of which I intend to use. The message payload otherwise is under 1472 bytes. Also, there doesn't seem to be a practical difference between dropped and ignored, except that checksum checking and dropping allows for hardware and OS optimization, whereas moving checksum calculation and ignoring to the application layer would cause a slight performance hit. Also importantly, dropped packets must be a vast minority.

Comment: Headers are not part of the payload. 'Vast minority' is a contradiction in terms, and 'must be' appears to contradict 'not a big deal'. UDP will drop packets whenever it feels like for whatever reason it judges sufficient, including but not limited to router queue overflow, receive buffer overflow, ...

Comment: Fair enough. What I meant was that dropped packets are not a problem so long as ~80%+ make it through, and the distribution of dropped packets is relatively random i.e. not the same nodes dropping packets each time. Clearly headers aren't part of the payload, but what I meant was that more headers means smaller possible payload. Sorry for the confusion.